# String index 0 ambiguity

Tags: python

Why is `''` a substring of all strings?

```
>>> string = 'string'

>>> '' in string
True
```

Why is it at index `0`?

```
>>> string.index('')
0
```

Why is index `0` ambiguous?

```
>>> string.index('s')
0

>>> string[string.index('')]
's'
```

Comment: For the same reason that the empty set is a subset of all sets.

Comment: Then why is `[] in list(string)` `False`? After all `[]` is an empty set.

Comment: @SvbZ3r0: Because `in` works differently for strings than for containers.  With every other container type, `x in ctr` tests whether `x` is an element of `ctr`, while `x in a_string` tests whether `x` is a substring of `a_string`.

Comment: @SvbZ3r0 `[]` is an empty list. `list(string)` is a list of single-char _strings_, it's not a list of _lists_. So why should you expect it to contain _any_ lists, empty or otherwise?

Comment: I will admit that Python strings are a little odd because a string is an ordered collection of its characters, but Python doesn't have a primitive character type, so those characters are represented as single element strings. This can be annoying, eg when recursively flattening a nested list / tuple that contains strings.

Comment: @jwodder I didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: @pm2ring i was going by your statement "for the same reason that the empty set is a subset of all sets". But i get the point. Thank you

Comment: @SvbZ3r0: Sorry if my 1st comment was a little misleading: I didn't mean to imply that a string is a set, just that there are parallels. BTW, a good place to discuss the rationale for Python's behaviour is the SO Python [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). We chat about all sorts of non-computer stuff too, but Python questions are always welcome, although we do ask you not to link your own fresh SO questions there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> string = 'string'
>>> string[0:0] == ''
True
>>> string.index('str')
0
>>> string[string.index('str')] == 'str'
False
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) says that `string.index(sub)` returns the first occurrence of a substring, which is why `string.index('')` returns `0` rather than some other index or a special return value.

Comment: Ok.. That makes sense. But why does it return index `0`? Aren't all indices `True` for an empty substring? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to return a custom flag for index of `''`?

Comment: @sVbZ3r0: Because `index` returns the first index where the substring occurs. You don't get a special return value for `'strstr'.index('str')` either.

Comment: Right! I'm an idiot! Update your answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

string.index(substring) returns the index position where substring begins, or -1 if it is not part of the original stirng.

By definition the empty string is a subset of all strings, i.e. all strings begin with the empty string and string.index('') returns 0, the first index of the string.

string[index] returns the character at the index position, in this case 0 returned by the begin index of the empty string

Comment: But why is it at `0`? Wouldn't it be more accurate if it returned a custom `empty substring` flag, like `-1` for if not present?

Comment: That is the flag for when the parameter of the index() method is not a substring of the original one